# .toggle class. is it possible that

Tags: jquery

I uploaded here my problem: [my problem example](http://awerty.atwebpages.com/)

My question: Is it possible that 'content B def' is visible first after page is loaded (or after refreshing)  without modifying order of

```
<a> href="..." C </a>
<a> href="..." B </a>
<a> href="..." A </a>
```

I want C B A order. Not B C A or B A C
My javascripting knowledge is basic but it's increasing fast..

Sorry for my english,

Thanks a lot for suggestions!
I'm struggling with this problem for a few days now.

HTML code:

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <meta content="charset=utf-8" />
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script defer src="js/swap.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <div id="view-c" class="swap-cont">
            <h1>content C xyz</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="view-a" class="swap-cont">
            <h1>content A abc</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="view-b" class="swap-cont">
            <h1>content B def</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="toggle">
            <a href="#view-c">C</a>
            <a href="#view-b">B</a>
            <a href="#view-a">A</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

swap.js:

```
    $(function() {
    var toggles = $('.toggle a'),
        codes = $('.swap-cont');

    toggles.on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.hasClass("active")) {
            toggles.removeClass("active");
            $this.addClass("active");
            codes.hide().filter(this.hash).show();
        }
    });
    toggles.first().click();
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to change the last line of your script from:

```
toggles.first().click();
```

to:

```
toggles.eq(1).click();
```

This line initializes your view by triggering click on default anchor.

You were *clicking* the first anchor, which is C. B is actually second, therefore you need to use the `.eq()` method, which selects the `n-th` element from the set and is documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Alternative (cleaner) approach would be adding a `defaultAnchor` class to default anchor and modify the script to:

```
 $('.defaultAnchor').click();
```

Comment: Could i go straight to A (for example) when i'm on the other page? toggles.eq(1).click(); will bring me to B always...

...so my question (problem) right now is to find method to see  #view-a for example after clicking link on the other page.... I thought that <a href="pagename.html#view-a">...</a>
shoud work but it's not working.

Thanks for help